# How to convert timezone of date type variable in oracle trigger

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

If I have date type variable

```
date_time date := sysdate; -- Suppose the timezone is EST.
```

Now, How I can convert the timezone of variable to UTC?

Comment: Do you want to change the value or just the timezone?  More explanation on what you are really trying to do would help.

Comment: Timezones (TZ) aren't associated with DATES, or even TIMESTAMPs. However, they are available with a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE defined column. That's why both answers below show SYSTIMESTAMP, as that "Returns the system date, including fractional seconds and time zone of the system on which the database resides"

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP at time zone 'UTC' FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Now how I can assign the result of this query to `date_time` variable?

Comment: You can use a pl/sql block. `DECLARE
   ts   VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
   SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP at time zone 'UTC' INTO ts FROM DUAL;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ts);
END;
/`

Comment: Please consider to accept this answer if it solved the problem !

Answer (score 0):

Its not very clear from your question what exactly you require but if I understood correctly you require time in UTC

```
SELECT CAST(sys_extract_utc(SYSTIMESTAMP) AS TIME) FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Now how I can assign the result of this query to `date_time` variable?

Comment: Yes you can have into clause to assign.